# Keeping variable from SSH stored into local session

Tags: ssh

How do I transfer a variable from an ssh session into my local session? There is a readme file on the remote host that I need to ssh into and then copy it over to my local terminal.

```
cat readme
```

outputs the readme file to terminal on the ssh session. I tried storing the output of the command in a variable, however when I exit the ssh session the variable is gone.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to transfer variables from an interactive `SSH` session to the client host. But you can do it as a separate command this way:

```
variable=$(ssh remotehost cat readme)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use scp.

From your local machine:

```
$ scp username@remoteip:/path/to/readme ./
```

Will copy the readme from the remote computer to the current local directory.